# get list of disabled buttons index

Tags: javascript

I've created an array b to store nine buttons, and an array c of numbers 0 to 9 represent the button location. What I want to do is when every time I click the button, the button will become disabled and the array c will also remove this button's number. Example: when I press button1, button2, button7, the c array will become [2,3,4,5,7,8] or if I press button 9, button 5, button 3, the c will become [0,1,3,5,6,7]. The button's part goes well, and I am struggling in how to  change array c.

My code so far, and I don't put button's click function here:

```
let b =[bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5,bt6,bt7,bt8,bt9]
let c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
function search(array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(b[i].disabled == true) {
// do something
    }
  }
}
//everytime click a button, the buttoon will be disabled and the c will change
search(c)
console.log(c)
```

I've tried using splice but the c's length has been changed and the outcome was not good

Comment: could you please elaborate more, what is it that you want.. is the array c not working expected?. if not can you share your outcome too?

Comment: I want to make a tic tac toe minimax alogrithm ai, and I wanted to use the method above to get the availble spots for ai to do the alogrithm. at fitst I tried `c.splice(i,1)` in the place of` //do something part `in my code. The console shows that the c's length also changed when I clicked the button, so I can't remove element in the right place.

Comment: try this c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var pos = 6 // means you want to delete number 7 in the arraay///
var NewArray = c.slice(0,pos).concat(c.slice(pos+1))

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you to push the index of nodes that are not disabled to the array rather than poping the disabled node.

```
let b =[bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5,bt6,bt7,bt8,bt9]
// let c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
function search(array) {
  let c = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(b[i].disabled == true) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      // push that to array
      c.push(i);
    }
  }
}
//everytime click a button, the buttoon will be disabled and the c will change
search(c)
console.log(c)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I will work on it now, and  I will let you know if it works in my code!

Answer (score 1):

one approach might be to create a new array push all the valid buttons there and return the new array.

```
let b =[bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5,bt6,bt7,bt8,bt9]
let c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
function search(array) {
  let newC = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(!b[i].disabled) {
      newC.push[i];
    }
  }
  return newC;
}
//everytime click a button, the buttoon will be disabled and the c will change
c = search(c)
console.log(c)
```

but if due to some reason you don't want to assign the result of `search` to `c`. you can do the following

```
let b =[bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5,bt6,bt7,bt8,bt9]
let c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

function copy1DArray(array){
  let newArray = [];
  for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

function search(array) {
  copiedArray = copy1DArray(array);
  for(let i = 0; i < copiedArray.length; i++) {
    if(b[i].disabled) {
      array.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
}
//everytime click a button, the buttoon will be disabled and the c will change
search(c)
console.log(c)
```

Javascript objects are reference types, you should never use operators like splice on them in a loop. It is always better to take a copy of the array as reference. Here the copy must be a deep copy. The copy function i have wrote here is not doing deep copy, but it will work for this case.

Comment: thanks for your effort on my question. I am working on it !

Comment: It works! I use the first method u gave. but I need to declare an array when I call the function. Otherwise c's length will also change and the index will mess up. My code: `let d = search(c); console.log(d)`